# Is there an equivalent of "control flow" in deep learning systems?

Tags: machine-learning

Traditional programs work significantly through control flow. I know that there are simple algorithms that have no control flow at all (i.e. they just perform a fixed sequence of executions), but I cannot imagine anyone building a large complex program without any control flow.

However, as far as I understand, there is no control flow in standard deep learning systems. They execute the same calculations for every input.

**Are there deep learning/NN-based systems with something similar to control flow?**

Comment: Decision trees (random forests).

Comment: @pdexter, edited